# Randomly multiply or divide a pandas column by 2

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column with integers that I would like to randomly divide or multiply. The result would look like this:

```
col_1   new_col         
2       1
2       1
4       8
4       2
4       8
4       8
```

Answer (score 2):

### `np.random.choice`

```
df['new_col'] = df['col_1'] * np.random.choice([2, 1/2], len(df))
```